# how to detect when a message gets edited

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Hi so I'm trying to make a discord bot that deletes certain words I've managed to do this but I want to make it so it will delete edited messages 
This is what I've got so far

```
client.on('messageUpdate', message => {
  if(config.FILTER_LIST.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
    message.delete()
  }
})
```

But it won't delete the messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageUpdate) cool doc page.

You can use `client.on('messageUpdate')`, which is triggered every time a message is edited.

```
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    newMessage.delete();
}
```

Disclaimer: this only works for cached messages, which means that your bot will only have access to the messages it was notified of when it was online. There is no way for the bot to have access to messages that were sent when it was offline.